# How can I create an array in the STM32-Cube IDE for Ports that are already defined from the autogenerated CubeMX Code?

Tags: arrays, c, typedef

I want to create an array for these Ports, that are already defined in the main.h:

/* Autogenerated Code */

```
#define YELLOW_0_Pin GPIO_PIN_10
#define YELLOW_0_GPIO_Port GPIOB
#define RED_0_Pin GPIO_PIN_8
#define RED_0_GPIO_Port GPIOA
#define YELLOW_1_Pin GPIO_PIN_10
#define YELLOW_1_GPIO_Port GPIOA
#define RED_1_Pin GPIO_PIN_3
#define RED_1_GPIO_Port GPIOB
#define GREEN_0_Pin GPIO_PIN_4
#define GREEN_0_GPIO_Port GPIOB
#define BLUE_0_Pin GPIO_PIN_5
#define BLUE_0_GPIO_Port GPIOB
#define GREEN_1_Pin GPIO_PIN_8
#define GREEN_1_GPIO_Port GPIOB
#define BLUE_1_Pin GPIO_PIN_9
#define BLUE_1_GPIO_Port GPIOB
```

I want to use this enum:

```
enum LED {RED_0, YELLOW_0, GREEN_0, BLUE_0, RED_1, YELLOW_1, GREEN_1, BLUE_1};
```

And with that I want to define an array to use them:

```
GPIO_TypeDef *gpio_ports[8] = {&RED_0_GPIO_Port, &YELLOW_0_GPIO_Port, GREEN_0_GPIO_Port,
        BLUE_0_GPIO_Port, RED_1_GPIO_Port, YELLOW_1_GPIO_Port, GREEN_1_GPIO_Port,
        BLUE_1_GPIO_Port};
```

I was thinking about something like that, but I always get the multiple definition error (obviously..).

Can this be solved with a struct for example?

The end use should be this: led_activate(RED0); And then the RED LED should be activated and so on..

Comment: For *what* do you get "multiple definition errors"? Perhaps you should not define that inside a header file, only declare it?

Comment: Yes this is true. I did not think about that. If I'm defining it in the .c file it is working.

    typedef struct {
    GPIO_TypeDef *port;
    uint16_t pin;
} pin_config_t;

typedef struct {
 pin_config_t red0;
 pin_config_t yellow0;
}config_pins_t;

config_pins_t pins = {
  .red0 = (RED_0_GPIO_Port, RED_0_Pin)
};

I'm thinking about this could be the better solution. But it is also not working well..

Answer (score 1):

`GPIOA`, `GPIOB` are definitions expanding to the integer converted to the pointer. They do not exist in memory and you can't take the address of it.

```
#define GPIOA ((GPIO_Typedef *)0x40000500
```

As they are pointers you do not need to take the address of it:

```
GPIO_TypeDef *gpio_ports[8] = {RED_0_GPIO_Port, YELLOW_0_GPIO_Port, GREEN_0_GPIO_Port,
        BLUE_0_GPIO_Port, RED_1_GPIO_Port, YELLOW_1_GPIO_Port, GREEN_1_GPIO_Port,
        BLUE_1_GPIO_Port};
```